# how to set the EditText with data from the SQLite database

Tags: android, sqlite, android-edittext

`enter code here`the INFO_MAIN.xml design view

[image]

I am developing an `android` app for my school project. A Table called "raw material master " is already created in the `database` and the data is also inserted. 
  Please refer to the image above, after the raw material name is entered in the edit text infront of the Raw Material(Textview) , i want the edittexts infront of info1,info2,info3 to be set with hints whose values will be fetched from the database table " raw material master". i have used the code below for setting the edittext values.

[IN INFO_MAIN.java]

```
 public void rawmat() {
        info1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String rawMat = rm.getText().toString(); //fetching text from 
                       //the edittext infront of raw material
                Cursor res = dbb.getInfo("Info1",rawMat);  //getinfo method is 
                        //in the database helper class , it is pasted below
                String info = res.getString(1);
                info1.setText(info);   // setting the edit text.
                res = dbb.getInfo("Info2",rawMat); // repeating the same 
                                     //procedure for the edittext of info2.
                info = res.getString(0);
                dbb.SetEt(info, info2);
                res = dbb.getInfo("Info3",rawMat);
                info = res.getString(0);
                dbb.SetEt(info, info3);
            }
        });
    }
```

[`IN DATABASEHELPER.java]

```
 public Cursor getInfo(String info,String rm)
    {
        SQLiteDatabase db=this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor res=db.rawQuery("select "+info+"from "+table_name1 + "where RawName ="+rm,null);
        res.moveToFirst();
        return res;
    }

 public void SetEt(String x, EditText et)
    {
        et.setHint(x);
    }`
```

This code doesnt work. Can you  please help me with finding solution to this.

[ after adding a text watcher for the raw material edit text]

```
 rm.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            String rawMat = rm.getText().toString();
            Cursor res = dbb.getInfo("Info1", rawMat);
            String info = res.getString(1);
            info1.setText(info);
            res = dbb.getInfo("Info2", rawMat);
            info = res.getString(0);
            dbb.SetEt(info, info2);
            res = dbb.getInfo("Info3", rawMat);
            info = res.getString(0);
            dbb.SetEt(info, info3);
        }
    });
```

Comment: In what way is the code not working? Does it crash? Is there just nothing appearing in the TextView? Does anything appear in the logcat? Does `res` contain any rows?

Comment: The code does not crash, it just does not give me the expected results . The edittext still asks me to enter value and the cursor keeps on blinking. I think res contains the row that will be returned from the sqlite query which i fired in the db.rawQuery method. Cursor res=db.rawQuery("select "+info+"from "+table_name1 + "where RawName ="+rm,null);

Comment: You can check the number rows contains within a cursor using the `getCount()` method. I find it strange that you're calling this within the `onClick()` method on a TextView, why not just run the code within `onResume` instead so the data is automatically populated when the Activity is ready? Or move it to activate on a button click instead.

Comment: it is not possible for the data to be automatically populated when the activity is ready because the raw material name is not available until then , i am selecting the values from the table on the basis of the raw material name which will be entered by the user , it is the primary key. i will still try to use the onResume() method and see if it works.

Comment: So if the user is entering a name which will then be looked up from the database, wouldn't it be better to add a [TextWatcher](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher) to your `EditText` and set `afterTextChanged()` as the trigger?

Comment: rm.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {@Override public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) { }@Override public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {   } @Override  public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) { String rawMat = rm.getText().toString();Cursor res = dbb.getInfo("Info1", rawMat);String info = res.getString(1); info1.setText(info); res = dbb.getInfo("Info2", rawMat); info = res.getString(0); dbb.SetEt(info, info2); res = dbb.getInfo("Info3", rawMat); info = res.getString(0); dbb.SetEt(info, info3);}});

Comment: Could you please add that code [as an edit to your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/52383658/edit)? It's unreadable as a comment.

Comment: I dont think you will be able to clearly understand the code in the above comment as i had to fit it all in clumsily within the limits . But i tried using the textwatcher to watch the edittext of raw material and then inserted the code to change the further edit texts in the after text changed method. But this was all in vain as after clicking on the raw material edit text, the app directly went to the main activity.

Comment: No, what I'm saying is to edit your question and put the code in there. Then it'll be readable, and you won't have the character limits.

Comment: so , i found the solution , i used a button and the on click method to do the operation needed. Just needed some change in the databaseHelper class Thanks for the help .